# Can't find my website page listed under admin/structure/pages

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

Driving me crazy! 
I have a website page: http://www.randymtrader.com/contact that I cannot find anywhere in drupal admin/structure/pages. There is nothing with the path /contact. Where else could it be listed? I need to edit the page.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The `/contact` page is provided by the Contact module, which you must have enabled. It displays the `contact_site_form` form, which is declared in `/modules/contact/contact.pages.inc`.

Configuration options for this form can be found at the `site.com/admin/structure/contact` URL.

If you're looking to change form structure, you may need to create a custom module and implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). If you're after changing layout, you may be able to get away with adding/moving blocks (in which case have a look at [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) for more options than the core blocks page), but more likely should use something like [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) to create a new page and insert a new contact block on it. You may want to have a look at the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module, which can be used to create & configure forms through the UI.